# How to conveniently customize the metronic theme in aspnetzero?

Tags: asp.net-boilerplate

Is there an easier way to customize the metronic theme that comes with the aspnetzero framework? I just want to create a single file to override variables in the metronic sass file but it seems like it's not compiling the metronic sass files.

There's no webpack file in aspnetzero since the angular files are generated using angular-cli. So I don't know what sass files are being tracked.

Answer (score -1):

The **.sass** files are not tracked, so you must compile those files yourself.

You can add styles to **layout.less**, which is tracked in **.angular-cli.json**.

Related:

- [Changing metronic 5 theme](https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=26385)
- [Changing branding color](https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=27224)

Comment: This actually has me wondering why changing those sass files gets angular-cli to re-build the project? I guess it's tracked? 

if i compile them by myself, wouldn't i duplicate the styles of metronic since i think the pre-compiled metronic files are already used by the framework?

Comment: theNotoriousHxc  - i am struggling to understand this also. Did you find an answer?